# Secure communication between iPads

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, ssl

In my iOS app I need a secure way for iPads to communicate with each other.

My first (unsecure) implementation was that one iPad would set-up a webserver and the other iPads would communicate with it through normal NSURLSession requests.

Now that Apple is getting more strict on using HTTPS (through App Transport Security), I want to tackle this problem and add a layer of security between the iPads.

I've been looking at the TLS implementation in GCDAsyncSocket (already using that for the webserver). But that introduces the matter of certificates, which is difficult: the iPads should be able to work offline in a LAN and they connect to each other on IP addresses.

ATS forces certificates to be issued by a known CA. And I can't force our customers to install a custom CA certificate on their iPads. Even if I could do that, generating certificates for those iPads would probably become a nightmare.

So my next idea is to implement my own protocol with a layer similar to TLS. But I would of course much prefer to use a well tested mechanism like TLS.

I hope that you guys have some good suggestions. I feel like I can't be the first one with a case like this, although a lot of people seem to rely on a remote server (and I really need offline capability).

My minimum iOS requirement is iOS 9 (iPad 2 compatible).

Answer (score 0):

App Transport Security is not applied to connections made to IP addresses. From the iOS documentation:

> ## [Availability of ATS for Remote and Local Connections](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW54)
>
> App Transport Security (ATS) applies only to connections made to public host names. The system does not provide ATS protection to connections made to:
>
> - Internet protocol (IP) addresses
> - Unqualified host names
> - Local hosts employing the `.local` top-level domain (TLD)
>
> To connect to an unqualified host name or to a `.local` domain, you must set the value of the `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` key to `YES`.

This is in large part because it's **impossible** to use TLS in a way that would be compliant with ATS requirements. Any competent CA will refuse to issue a certificate for a private IP address or hostname, and will revoke a certificate if they discover that its key has been compromised (say, by being distributed in a mobile application).

With regard to writing your own encryption: Don't. Handling security in a peer-to-peer configuration like you're describing is complicated. More importantly, including your own encryption code in an application will make distributing it outside the US more complicated. You're best off here relying on the security of the wireless network to protect your communications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I prefer not to rely only on wifi security. A lot of our customers decide that it is ok to share their wifi with their guests. I might be able to set-up a custom CA, assign the iPads certificates and bypass hostname validation (and use TLS). However I believe that ATS is applied to IP addresses under iOS 9. Apple fixed some of the mishaps with ATS in iOS 10 (for example by introducing the NSAllowsLocalNetworking key you wrote about), but that leaves me with some headache for iOS 9.

Comment: I can confirm that the documentation is for iOS 10. In iOS 9 HTTP requests on IP addresses are blocked by ATS.